# how do i get a spotify artist image/portrait?

Tags: image, api, model, spotify

I am trying to get an artist's image/portrait.  However, using Artist.fromURI() will return an artist object but  no portrait.  I read some other postings on StackOverflow where someone suggested using:

```
sp.core.browseURI()
```

because fromURI only retrieves basic information for performance reasons. However recently spotify has stated that we are no longer allowed to use sp.core calls.  So what is the alternative?

Instead this is what i'm using:

```
models.Artist.fromURI(uri, function(artist) {
   // this is called when artist is loaded but the following shows blank even
   // when the artist has an image
   console.log(artist.data.portrait);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Artist` object has the `image` property, which is filled with a URI once the artist has loaded.

Once you have that URI, you can simply use it as you would any other image URI - put it in an `img` element, etc.

It's worth noting that some artists don't have portraits. In this case, you should use one of their album's covers instead.

Comment: i still do not see any image for the artist, even artists i know for sure have images (because the spotify artist page shows images for this artist).  i am using models.Artist.fromURI() and in the callback (which is called when the artist is *loaded* ) i do not see a 'portrait'.  Also the Artist object in the documentation has an 'image' property but they say to use Artist.fromURI() which returns an object that contains a 'portrait' property, not image.  How are you *loading* this artist?